# [PHP] Как вытащить значение из кода html?

Tags: php

Я получаю текст страницы, в куске кода

```
<a class="color2" href="profile/ID/">NAME</a>
```

ID известен, нужно вытащить NAME

Как это можно сделать на PHP?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$text = '<a class="color2" href="profile/ID/">NAME</a>';
$regexp = "#href=\"profile/{$id}/\">([^<]*)<\/a>#";
preg_match($regexp, $text, $match);
var_dump($match);
```